# mod_rewrite: Excluding subdirectory from RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite

The following rewrite Rule in .htaccess does not work as expected. It does not exclude /FileShare subdirectory from the rewrite rule although it should:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/FileShare
RewriteRule ([0-9]+) Router.php?id=$1 [QSA]

# Still call existing files (for css, gfx etc.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Redirect every other file call 
RewriteRule ^.*$ Router.php [QSA]
# Redirect every other call even without file name in it
RewriteRule ^$ Router.php [QSA]
```

Desired outcome is

```
/Command/Method -> Router.php
/Command/Method/123 -> Router.php?id=123
/FileShare/Command/Method -> Router.php
/FileShare/Command/Method/123 -> Router.php (without stripping 123 and without id=123)
```

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the above script does work. The problem was that Router.php did not react correctly.